# Running Gnome on CentOS 6.4 using remote connect doesn't work

Tags: linux, gnome, centos6

I am connecting remotely (using putty) to a VPS that's running CentOS 6.4. I tried starting the GUI by typing "startx" in the terminal and it told me the command was not found, thus I assume that this version of the OS does not have Gnome included.

I installed Gnome using the following command

```
yum groupinstall basic-desktop desktop-platform x11 fonts
```

After the installation finished I typed "startx" and the GUI began to start. It loads until I receive the error:

```
error setting MTTR (base = 0xf8000000, size = 0x00400000, type = 1) Invalid argument (22) 
Window
```

Is this due to an incompatibility with the GUI I installed or is there another reason for this?

Comment: Do you have X protocol forwarding set up?

Comment: No I have not, I'm pretty new to linux. If you can provide any more information on what I would need to do I'd appreciate greatly.

Comment: I've figured out so far that the issue is most likely due to configuration issues with putty. Still trying to get it to work though.

Comment: `startx` would start a X server on the server directly. As you're not sitting in front of it, that will not help you. Try installing a VNC server instead an X server, and use a SSH tunnel to access it. There are many tutorials to guide you, [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vncserver) should contain anything you need.

Comment: You might want to re-work your title to reflect your predicament more accurately, saying "Running Gnome on CentOS 6.4 doesn't work" is a bit mis-leading. :)

Comment: @ffledgling, thanks, I changed the title, hope its more appropriate now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, the most obvious problem is that you don't have X protocol forwarding set up (X11 is a client/server system where, quite confusingly, a *client* is a program running sometimes on a remote machine and it communicates with an *X Server* which you can think of as a graphical system running on your local desktop).

You can set up Putty to forward your X connections but it is a bit involved for a newbie. Instead, consider using [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) which is an out-of-the-box solution providing both X server and remote terminal facility. With it, you can SSH into your Linux box and start X programs ("clients") which will show up on your desktop.

Comment: Thanks very much! Very nice software, didn't take too long to figure out.